# Determining the distribution for a sample data set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

I have a sample data set of heights of students where

```
X = (1.65,1.55,1.78,1.43,1.69)
```

and I'm required to fit a normal distribution to the data X.

The thing I'm confused now is, should i use a Gaussian Distribution or a Poisson Distribution? I know that Poisson is used mainly for the purpose of counting occurrences but i also discovered that the normal distribution is the Gaussian Distribution but I'm not really clear about it.

Is the Gaussian Distribution the only distribution that is considered normal distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) is the same as Gaussian distribution. To fit your data to a normal distribution, i.e. find the parameters of Gaussian (Normal) distribution just put:

$$
\hat{\mu} = \frac{X_1 + \dots + X_5} {5}, \quad \hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{(X_1 - \hat{\mu})^2 + \dots + (X_5 - \hat{\mu})^2}{4}.
$$
Then, your fitted distribution will be $\mathcal{N}\left(\hat{\mu}, \hat{\sigma}^2\right)$.

---

Note that we divided by $4$ (in second equation above), which, in general case, is $n - 1$, since this estimate for $\hat{\sigma}^2$ is the unbiased one.

Comment: thank you. I would like to confirm that if I'm told to fit a 'normal distribution', that means that it is definitely the Gaussian Distribution not Poisson distribution am i correct?

Comment: yes! see the link I provided in my answer.